# how to get a curl json post statement to work in php

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have a curl post request that posts Json to an api end point but for the life of me I cant get it working in php.
Here is the working curl:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Access-Token: **not_telling_you**" -X POST --data '{"import":{"members":[{"organization_customer_identifier":"a number", "program_customer_identifier":"a number", "first_name":"Chris", "member_customer_identifier":"5", "member_status":"OPEN"} ]}}'  https://an_api_endpoint.com/api/v1/imports
```

Here is the php that does not work:

```
$org_id = "a number";
$pc_id = "a number";
$user_id = "5";
$api_key = "**not telling you**";
$url = "https://an_api_endpoint.com/api/v1/imports";
$data = json_encode(array('import' => array( 'members' => array( array('organization_customer_identifier' => $org_id, 'program_customer_identifier' => $pc_id, 'member_customer_identifier' => $user_id, 'member_status' => 'OPEN')))));
echo $data;
echo "\n";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Access-Token: '.$api_key));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($output, true);
var_dump($result);
```

I keep getting errors like `{"message":"Invalid JSON in request body, please validate your JSON and try again."}`int(1)
or upon switching things up a bit it might be:`["message"]=>string(29)` `"Invalid API key () specified."`

I thought it would be easier for me to translate curl into php curl but I cant seem to get this one working. I even tried copying and pasting in the json data directly so it would be exactly the same and its not working still.
I'm not sure if I'm missing something or my order is bad?
Thank you in advance for any help I get solving this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option multiple times. You use it once with an array of all the headers.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json', 
    'Content-Type:application/json', 
    'Access-Token: '.$api_key));
```

You're also missing the `CURLOPT_POST` option.

You might want to use this site. You paste in a `curl` command and it converts it to PHP.

https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Comment: Thank you! That makes so much more sense. Yea the post was in there but got pealed away as I was trying out different variations.

Comment: following your example worked and made a lot of sense. Also thank you for the helpful link so I don't get stuck like this again! Your answer completely answers my questions and future questions and the questions of people similar to mine. Thank you!